# How to make a Spring JMS listener automatically recover from closed consumers?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

In an attempt to mitigate the effect of deadlocks in my application I am considering setting up my ActiveMQ server to [abort slow consumers](https://dzone.com/articles/coming-activemq-59-new-way). I can get this working OK, but the problem is that my Spring `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` never restarts the closed consumers, somewhat defeating the point of detecting when a consumer is blocked.

I have tried the following:

- Changed the cache level of the container to `CACHE_NONE` ensure it's not a problem with it keeping hold of a closed consumer/session
- Switched to a raw `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` rather than a `PooledConnectionFactory` to ensure it's not the pool keeping hold of a closed session/connection
- Reverted to the default `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` rather than a pooled executor to ensure it's not a problem with keeping hold of threads that are somehow stuck

None of these have worked. Is there a way to get the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` to automatically create new consumers if they are closed by ActiveMQ?

Comment: `> deadlocks in my application ` - if the listener container thread(s) are "stuck" in the listener code, there is nothing the container can do - it can't detect the closed consumer until the thread returns to the container. You need to fix the deadlocks, sorry.

Comment: I see, thanks. I was simulating a deadlocked thread by using an effectively infinite Thread.sleep; however I have changed this to simply sleep for a minute or so and the consumers come back once the thread returns, thus proving your point.